# Is "cryptofree.best" website a scam for mining? How does it works?

Tags: fraud, websites

Few days ago someone introduced me website "[cryptofree.best](https://cryptofree.best/)" and told me that you can collect Bitcoin in this website just by a few clicks on "Roll" button and by spending at least 1 hours/day. And tempted me that you can collect 1 BTC without spending any money in 3 months. But he pointed out that the rule of the above website is minimum 1 BTC for withdrawal. In that website if you invite an active user to the website then you will receive additional bitcoin as a reward/bonus.

He also tried to convince me by commenting that one of his friends had successfully cashed his money.

But how is that possible?  Are they misusing our smartphone/computer graphics remotely. If not why they are paying for free?

> Are all website like "[cryptofree.best](https://cryptofree.best/)" a scam for mining?

(I am not sure about tags. Feel free to edit.)

Comment: Definitely sounds like a scam to me. To mine 1 BTC (~10,0000 USD) requires a large investment in mining hardware at this stage. Lots and lots of scams around unfortunately. If it seems too good to be true it is extremely likely it is.

Comment: So what is the benefits of this type of scams? just increasing the website viewer?

Comment: I don't know and I don't want to spend time looking into it, sorry. Maybe you install cryptocurrency mining malware where the benefits (which are considerably less than 1 BTC but not zero) accrue to the malware authors

Comment: If you have to ask whether it's a scam, it is a scam.

Comment: I am sure 99%. And according your comments now 100%.

Comment: See https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/99340/13866