# Where is my account?

Tags: fraud

I received 0.2 bitcoins on this site and deposited it in my wallet, why it was not deposited.
https://cryptofree.casa/free#

Answer (score 3):

> **why it was not deposited.**

This happens sometimes when people give money to a website without first checking whether that website is genuine and whether the offered benefits are realistic.

Investors who don't check carefully are especially vulnerable to fraud.

---

Your account is with a website that is often connected with fraud or scam.

- [Is cryptofree.casa genuine plateform to earn free BTC](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/105533/13866)
- [What happens to the bitcoin mining if the device changes?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/100427/13866)
- [Is "cryptofree.best" website a scam for mining? How does it works?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/99320/13866)

---

See also

- [How to tell if a cryptocurrency exchange or trading platform is trustworthy?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/98743/13866)
- [How do I recover from a cryptocurrency scam?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/91943/13866)